# Close/hide video after playing

Tags: html, mp4

I have a fullwidth autoplaying muted mp4 on my site. I want it to close/hide when it reaches the end - and instead show a form. Is that possible? Perhaps by redirecting to another page automatically, if the other is not an option.

```
    <div class="videoWrapper">
 <video controls autoplay muted>
   <source src="https://www.tectonicentertainment.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/TECTONIC.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag
 </video>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Did you embed the video in your website (you mention _site_)? If so, what did you use? Can you show us the code? What's the result and what is wrong about the result (include screenshots if possible)? Also have you read through the [How-to-ask-page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? If not, I suggest you to do that first :)

Comment: Thanks. The html is added to my question now. Nothings wrong - I just wanted to know if anyone knows a way to close/hide the video after plaing. Haven't found anything useful in my search for an answer...

Comment: Welcome _ If no-one can provide a good answer_ & thinking 'laterally': If the video is a permanent fixture on the site you could use the play-length to set a timer with javascript which carries out later events _ such as hide `videoWrapper` and show `formWrapper`in its place

Comment: A lot better now :) I think what you're looking for is the [`onended`-event](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/av_event_ended.asp). I'm not confident enough to post it as an answer but take a look at it :)

Comment: Thanks for suggestions - it's a little out of my league I think. Must think of another scenario.

Comment: @KatrineBB see if my answer solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> *"I want it to close/hide when it reaches the end - and instead show a form. Is that possible? Perhaps by redirecting to another page automatically, if the other is not an option."*

**(1)** To detect video ending add `onended` to your video tag. Example:  `onended="doSomeFunctionName()"`

**(2)** To update a `<div>` use `innerHTML`, or else to redirect the page use `window.location.replace`

Testable example: (notice that the `<div>` has been given an ID so we know which thing to update)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="myVidContainer" class="videoWrapper">
<video controls autoplay muted onended="myVideoFinished()">
<source src="https://www.tectonicentertainment.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/TECTONIC.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag
</video>
</div>

<script>

function myVideoFinished() 
{
    alert("The video has ended");

    //# create FORM code in some string
    var form_code = "<form action='/action_page.php' method='get'>"
    form_code += "First name: <input type='text' name='fname'><br>"
    form_code += "Last name: <input type='text' name='lname'><br>"
    form_code += "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>"
    form_code += "</form>"

    //# replace Video tag with Form
    document.getElementById("myVidContainer").innerHTML = form_code;

    //# or Redirect to another page
    //window.location.replace("https://www.google.com")     
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```